# User's Role From Extended Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

What I'm attempting to do here is mainly in the Dashboard Controller. As of right now I have the index function using Phil Sturgeon's template library to build the dashboard as the main content view. I have a few things to consider here. I have administrators and basic users that are able to see the dashboard. Administrators will be able to see different information from inside of the dashboard that a basic user can see like site information, pending registrations, etc.

Should I have a separate dashboard view for the different types of users?

If so, how can I access the user_data from the Admin_Controller so that I can do a if statement check in the index function of the dashboard to see what type of user they are?

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Admin_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public $data = array();
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this -> load -> model('user_model', 'user');
        $user_id = $this -> session -> userdata('user_id');
        $user_data = $this -> user -> get($user_id);
        $this -> data['user_data'] = $user_data;
        $this -> template -> set_theme('saturn') -> set_layout('default', 'admin') -> set_partial('navigation', 'admin/partials/navigation') -> set_partial('header', 'admin/partials/header');
    }
}

<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Dashboard extends Admin_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this -> template -> build('admin/dashboard', $this -> data);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I"m trying to figure out I can access the $user_data object from the Admin_Controller so that I can run the if statement like this.

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Dashboard extends Admin_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        if ($user_data -> role_id == 2)
        {
            $dashboard = 'admin_dashboard';
        }
        else
        {
            $dashboard = 'user_dashboard';
        }
        $this -> template -> build('admin/'.$dashboard, $this -> data);
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Does anybody know how I can pass the data object to the dashboard controller so that it can be used to do the if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I have a separate dashboard view for the different types of
>   users?

Depends on the dashboard structure. If it is totally different for regular user and admin, it might be better to build an individual dashboards for booth user types. If there are some common elements, you can use if statement inside a view, to check user type and use the righ dashboard parts. This is more about your convenience, than a convention.

> If so, how can I access the user_data from the Admin_Controller so
>   that I can do a if statement check in the index function of the
>   dashboard to see what type of user they are?

You should rather pass user_data array to the view, than read session data from it. View part od your system should always get all data directly from the controller, not from session, or any other application component.

Answer (score 0):

Well I can give a suggestion as you will have one administrator account which must be there always, consider it will be the first record of your user table (AS BOTH ADMINISTRATOR AND USERS WILL BE SAME TABLE AND WILL DIFFERENT ROLES), so the id will be 1 and I guess it should be, so in your Dashboard Controller

```
public function index()
{
      if($this -> session -> userdata('user_id') == 1){
         $this -> template -> build('admin/dashboard', $this -> data);
      }else{
         //user dashboard.
      }

}
```

ELSE you can have define it by your roles, like admin have Role Id = 1.

I hope it helped you.